# to convert an array to json by papaparse jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I am trying to implement the jQuery plugin *[Papa Parse](http://papaparse.com/)*. However, it does not seems to be working. It should need to convert my array into JSON. I have parsed CSV into array

```
        // parse csv line by line
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = parseLineCSV(arr[i]);
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {

            }
            document.write(arr[i]);
        }
    } else {
        document.write("Not a CSV file!")
    }
}
```

I have my data in `arr` but I am unable to convert it to JSON. The following code I have taken from *Papa Parse* tutorials but it does not seems to be working. If anyone knows how to do that please.

```
//papa parse code to convert to json
var results = $.parse(arr, {
    delimiter: "\t",
    header: true,
    dynamicTyping: false,
    preview: 0,
    step: function (data, file, inputElem) {
        console.log("Row data:", data.results);
        console.log("Row errors:", data.errors);
        console.log(data.results);
    },
    complete: function () {
        console.log("All done!");
    }
});
```

Comment: please format your code well...

Answer (score 1):

Create an array and then push your results into this array.
Your input is meant to be a CSV though (string, file URL) not an array.

```
var ur_data = []

var results = $.parse(arr, {
    delimiter: "\t",
    header: true,
    dynamicTyping: false,
    preview: 0,
    step: function (results) {
        ur_data.push(results.data[0]);
    },
    complete: function () {
        console.log("All done!");
    }
});
```